# What does "bodded ill" mean?

Tags: expressions, idioms, idiom-meaning

Quoted from [here](http://creativeconsort.proboards.com/thread/1582):

"Not to make an impression but anyone that **bodded ill** with the Duchess, did not sit with with Ealora"

I was wondering what the expression "bodded ill" means.

Thank you.

P.S. As you can see [here](http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=bodded%20ill&word2=boded%20ill), Google suggest that "bodded" written form is far more popular than "boded".

Comment: It may be a typo for [*boded*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bode). When I glanced at the page, I noticed other typos.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo.

Comment: The source is, by the way, amazingly bad, with two or three errors of diction or idiom or syntax in every line.

Comment: No, definitely not a typo, I have seen "bodded ill" in more dependable contexts too. Actually, the fact that many of you think it is a typo, makes the question more interesting.

Comment: it's simply **a spelling mistake**, it's "boded".

Comment: [Nothing for bodded ill in NGRAM](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=boded+ill%2Cbodded+ill&year_start=1800&year_end=2014&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cboded%20ill%3B%2Cc0) nor in a [real search](https://www.google.com/search?q="bodded+ill"+OR+"boded+ill)

Comment: All bad attempts at *bode* ill.  'Bode' is already past tense, and should not be further inflected.  'Bode' is the past tense of 'bid', one archaic meaning of which is 'to notify'.  'Bode ill' means 'implied negative things are going to happen.'

Comment: It's not "boded". "Bode" is a future-tense verb meaning "to augur or foretell" - thus, "The old gypsy woman glanced at my hand. 'GASP!', she gasped, 'This does not bode well of a long, happy life for you! CROSS MY PALM WITH SILVER WHILE YET YOU MAY!'. 'What is it?', I cried. 'What does my future hold!?'. 'I see...', she said, glancing out the tent-flap and speaking quickly, 'a vehicle...a terrible accident!'. 'When?!', I cried, scattering my purse upon the table. Behind me I heard tires squealing and a truck horn, sounding closer.  'Soon!', she said, diving to her left, 'VERY, VERY SOON..!".

Comment: I stumbled up from my chair and fell to my left! There was a mighty rumbling - a deafening wall of sound - a roaring wind - mud spraying everywhere! And then...silence. Peace. Quiet. And the sound of the old gypsy woman's voice, as from afar. "Well...I got the vehicle...and the terrible accident...but no one was killed! Oh, well - two out of three ain't bad!" she said, as she plucked the notes and coins from the mud. "But", I said, "my fortune..?". "Your fortune? Take a little advice from an old lady - don't sit with your back to the tent flap!", she cackled. "And...have a nice day!". :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a typo or variant of *[boded ill](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/bode?q=bode%20ill)*

> (bode well/ill)
>   Be an omen of a particular outcome:
>   *their argument did not bode well for the future*
>
> [WITH OBJECT]: *the 12 percent interest rate bodes dark days ahead for retailers*
>
> [*Oxford Dictionary Online*]

In context, it seems to indicate *make a bad impression* (and likely suffer future disfavor).

Comment: http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=bodded+ill&word2=boded+ill  . It is curious that Google shows more instances of 'bodded ill' than 'boded ill'.

Comment: @Josh61 If you put quotes around the phrases, the results flip.

Comment: @Josh61 If you run an ngram search, *bodded ill* returns no results. The term *bodded* shows up as jargon in a few fields, such as geology, but does not appear to be used in the sense offered here.

Comment: @Josh61 Also, no online dictionaries in onelook.com list it.